# Xcode 9.2 fails to debug custom keyboard extension strangely

Tags: swift, xcode, debugging, keyboard

I am trying to build an example program to demonstrate the custom keyboard feature. I used to build such program under xcode 8 and everything goes fine. but when I upgrade to Xcode 9.2 , I found the IDE failed to debug at the breakpoint even I use "step over(F6)", and Xcode9.2 always display "Thread 1: signal SIGQUIT" and missing other breakpoint behind. Is there any problem ? Did I missed something ?
[image]

Comment: What is type of nextKeyboardButton property?

Comment: It was the default custom keyboard program produce by Xcode ide , I didn't modify anything .

Comment: the property of nextkeyboardbutton is UIBUTTON that is mentioned in the picture, all custom keyboard code is default example code from xcode

Comment: did somebody meet same situation that is custom keyboard project cannot be debug by step from just system defaut example code？

Comment: In my case I found out debugging extensions with Xcode is almost impossible whenever I debug todays extension or Xcode extension or any other extension... but crashing on with sigquit takes it to the whole new level

Comment: but you can use `console! app output o checkout the values...

Comment: I used to debug my custom keyboard project under Xcode 8 without such problem ,  It seems to be a bug of Xcode 9.2  ?   how can we bypass this problem by change some options ?

Comment: although I can use console output to see some values but the integrated project still needs to be inspect inside for runtime , for we can discover the matters betweens objects inside easier .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with XCODE9.2, and I solve this problem by depolying a real ipad for debug, then I can debug the program step by step.

Comment: I was also able to get to debugging when I ran it on an iPhone device.